# Styling dropdown menu html with Chosen.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, jquery-chosen

I have javascript to create a dropdown menu on the onchange event of another menu. My first menu is styled with Chosen.js and works fine, my second menu is not getting styled as it should. I have tried using `&quot;` in case I needed to use double rather than single quotes, this broke the second dropdown and I don't understand why.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Operations</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="docsupport/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="docsupport/prism.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="chosen.css">
</head>
<body class="back3">
        <select id="zone" select data-placeholder="Choose a Zone..." class="chosen-select" style="width:450px;">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="North America">North America</option>
            <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
            <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
            <option value="North Africa">North Africa</option>
        </select>

    <div id="country">
    </div>

        <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="docsupport/prism.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var config = {
                '.chosen-select': {disable_search: true},
                '.chosen-select-deselect': { allow_single_deselect: true },
                '.chosen-select-no-single': { disable_search_threshold: 10 },
                '.chosen-select-no-results': { no_results_text: 'Oops, nothing found!' },
                '.chosen-select-width': { width: "100%" }
                
            }
            for (var selector in config) {
                $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
            }
            $('#zone').change(function () {
                $('#country').html("<select id='first_selected' select data-placeholder='Choose a Country...' class='chosen-select' style='width:450px;'></select>");
                for (var i = 0; i < $(this).val().length; i++) {
                    $('#first_selected').append('<option value="' + $(this).val()[i] + '">' + $(this).val()[i] + '</option>');
                }
            })
        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).val()` will hold the value selected from the first menu, therefore the following code will iteretate over it, letter by letter:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $(this).val().length; i++) {
    $('#first_selected').append('<option value="' + $(this).val()[i] + '">' + $(this).val()[i] + '</option>');
}
```

I have create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f1bpkgne/), mybe it will help you (please note that the fiddle doesn't have a reference to the chose plugin lib).